# I'm unable to get return value of stored procedure which returns result set as well as return value

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures, resultset

I am trying to execute a MSSQL stored procedure from Excel VBA using ADODB 2.0 library (tried 2.8 also but same issue exist)
which sends result set as well as return value. I am able to get the result set values correctly but unable to get return value (always getting return value as empty.)

Below is the VBA procedure used for this purpose and this takes the following parameters:
`db connection, sp name,  parameter values string array, db result set, spretval` -- last two are out parameters

```
Private Sub execSQLSP(dbcon, spname, paramStrInArray, ByRef dbrs, ByRef spretval)
 Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
 Dim dberrflag As Integer
 Dim dberrdesc As String
 Dim ndx As Long
 Dim paramname As String
 On Error Resume Next

 Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
 Set cmd.ActiveConnection = dbcon
 cmd.CommandText = spname
 cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

 cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("retVal", adInteger, _ 
                                           adParamReturnValue)

 For ndx = 0 To UBound(paramStrInArray)
     paramname = "param" & ndx
     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Name:=paramname, _
                               Type:=adVarChar, Direction:=adParamInput, _
                               size:=Len(paramStrInArray(ndx)), _
                               Value:=paramStrInArray(ndx))
 Next

Set dbrs = cmd.Execute     
 Call getDBerror(dbcon.Errors, dberrflag, dberrdesc)
 If dberrflag = 1 Then
    MsgBox "DB Error while executing following SQL command and hence stopping." & vbCrLf & _
           "SQL Cmd:" & spname & vbCrLf & _
           "DB Err.:" & dberrdesc, vbCritical, appnameversion
    cleanup
    End
 End If
 spretval = cmd.Parameters("retVal").Value
 MsgBox cmd.Parameters("retVal")
End Sub
```

After execution of this VBA procedure, getting result set using which I am able to get the result set values correctly but NOT return value. I am Getting only empty value (actually the SP returns 10)

The stored procedure contains some processing to insert data into temporary tables, and finally returns all the rows from the temp table via a select command, and after that, return value.

What could be the issue with this code?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the return value when I queried the return value after closing the recordset object.

Apparently it is not just enough to read the recordset fully; the recordset object needs to be closed as well for the return and parameter values to be populated in the command object. I could not find this in the ADO documentation.

It looks like this may be an ADO design issue that command object return/parameter values are getting populated only after closure of the recordset object.